# Do i need to import the child CA certificate when root certificate is already exist in cacert file?

Tags: java, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

i have my application app1 verified by trsutswave whose root certificate is Entrust.net.I can not see the entry of trustwave  in cacerts file 
of app2 though entrust exist there. My question is do i till need to import the trustwave certificate inside cacert file of app2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think not, trust is transitive.